# How is byte alignment done with malloc()?

Tags: c

I am currently reading a program used to aligned memory allocation and free allocated memory. Here is the C code:

```
/**
 * Aligned memory allocation
 * param[in] size Bytes to be allocated
 * param[in] alignment Alignment bytes
 * return Address of allocated memory
 */
inline void* _al_malloc(size_t size, size_t alignemt)
{
    size_t a = alignment - 1;
    size_t word_length = sizeof(void*);
    void* raw = malloc(word_length + size + a);
    if (!raw)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    void* ptr = (void*)((size_t(raw) + word_length + a) & ~a);
    *((void**)ptr - 1) = raw;
    return ptr;
}



/**
 * Free allocated memory
 */
inline void _al_free(void * ptr)
{
    if (!ptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    void* raw = *((void**)ptr - 1);
    free(raw);
}
```

How do these operations ensure byte aligned memory?

Comment: use C11 `aligned_alloc()`, the returned pointer can be passed to `free()`.

Comment: It allocates extra memory, and then moves the start address of the returned pointer so that it is properly aligned (by possibly leaving a few bytes unused).

Comment: hi@BoPersson，but why the length of unused bytes is word_length + a ?

Answer (score 3):

It allocates extra memory, and then moves the start address of the returned pointer so that it is properly aligned (by possibly leaving a few bytes unused).

More detailed:

```
size_t a = alignment - 1;
```

If `alignment` is a power of 2, this will give both the number of extra bytes needed and a mask for address bits not allowed in an aligned pointer.

For example, if alignment is 8 we might need to allocate 7 extra bytes to be sure that one of them is aligned at 8.

```
size_t word_length = sizeof(void*);
```

Compute the size of an extra pointer (needed by `free` later).

```
void* raw = malloc(word_length + size + a);
```

Allocate the needed memory block + size of a pointer + extra bytes we might need for alignment.

```
if (!raw)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Return a null pointer if we fail.

```
void* ptr = (void*)((size_t(raw) + word_length + a) & ~a);
```

Now get a new pointer that is the raw pointer + space for saving + the number of bytes needed for proper alignment.

```
*((void**)ptr - 1) = raw;
```

Also save the original pointer from `malloc`, beacause that is needed to `free` it later.

```
return ptr;
```

Done.

Comment: So this code is broken if a non-power-of-2 alignment is passed?

Comment: Probably. I have never seen any align-5 data.  :-)  For protection, we might want to add a check that the alignment has a proper value.

Comment: @BoPersson, still wondering why void* ptr = (void*)((size_t(raw) + word_length + a) & ~a); can get the proper address

Comment: @CJZ - It uses some odd bit-fiddling. It first computes an address (that doesn't have to be aligned) and then uses the bitmask `~a` to mask off the last bits of the address. With align 8, the last 3 bits are zero. With align 16, the last 4 bits. It has allocated enough extra space to ensure that this will also be inside the allocated block.