# How to align memory address?

Tags: c, embedded

Can anyone could tell me how to align a 16-bit memory address to the nearst 2kB address boundry in C?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because So is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: See also @Bo Persson's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307822/how-is-byte-alignment-done-with-malloc, asked 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Do you want to align to **nearest** or **towards zero**?

Comment: I want to align it to nearest

Comment: And that shall be a variable, I presume? So all answers are actually wrong. Please add both informations to your question and state if you can use C11 (if not, how about C99) and which compiler you are actually using.

Comment: a = (a+0x7FF) & (~0x7FF);  not necessarily to nearest.

Comment: Olaf,
Could you tell me how I can make the allocation with both C11 and C99. I have to correct a small detail in my question, if fact I want to align a random 32-bit memory address to the nearest 2KB address boundary. (I want to dynamically adjust the address)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it on yourself, or you need it for dynamic allocations/addressings you ca use the following simple computation:

```
Aligned2kBoundary = (Unaligned + 2047) & ~(2047);
```

In a more generalized form if `bound` is your boundary value:

```
Aligned2kBoundary = (Unaligned + bound -1) & ~(bound-1);
```

**Warning**: Works only for boundaries that are powers of 2!

PS for who have not noticed it, this question is for an embedded system and maybe he wants to dynamically adjust the address while running, not while compiling.

Comment: Bitops with a pointer?

Comment: Tell me! Point is, if you use something more recent than bad ol' K&R C (i.e. do not work at assember-level with regard of type-safety), the compiler will not allow this - for very good reasons. C has evolved since the PDP-11 with C99 being a major leap in enforcing quality. However, it also introduced ways to still do what is needed, but in a better documented and (slightly) more secure way. If you are **that** much of an expert, you should know about `uintptr_t`, for instance.

Comment: Oh, and I add the SC/MP-II, 6502, 68HC11, 68HC08, PIC, Cortex-M4 plus some own cores to the list. Not to mention various RTOS-designs and bare-metal (which was normal on an 6502 home-brew with only 2KiB EPROM that time).

Comment: @Olaf you're right I should have put `uintptr_t` or `(ulong_t)(void *)`. I wan't appear like such an 'expert' (this is my business, and I'm not in need to), but to be practical. Maybe I'm wrong, but because I'm very busy (still working) I try to answer even if with some approximation to give help. I appreciate comments, means that someone take care of my scripts, but if they downvote means that the answer is wrong, and honestly this doesn't seem the case. Because this behavior seems to be very common I will refrain from give any answer not have enough time to craft a perfect product.

Answer (score 2):

In C11 you can allocate dynamic memory and specify the alignment with function `aligned_alloc`. You can also use C11 `_Alignas` specifier.

Most compilers also have extensions to specify alignment for example gcc has `aligned` attribute. From [documentation](http://aligned%20(alignment)%20This%20attribute%20specifies%20a%20minimum%20alignment%20for%20the%20variable%20or%20structure%20field,%20measured%20in%20bytes.):

> aligned (alignment)
>
> This attribute specifies a minimum alignment for the variable or structure field, measured in bytes. For example, the declaration:
>
> ```
>      int x __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = 0;
> ```

Comment: I somewhat doubt OP has `malloc` etc. availabe. Why not use `alignas`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [aligned_alloc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) to allocate aligned memory chunk. If you want to align local variables, you can use compiler attributes. In GCC it is [aligned](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)

For example:

```
 int x __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = 0;
```

For Visual C++ it is also [aligned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx)

For example:

```
__declspec(align(16)) struct Str1{
   int a, b, c, d, e;
};
```

Comment: Why use proprietary extensions in the first place?