# How to mprotect() existing address to enable PROT_WRITE without using mmap()? (is it even possible)?

Tags: c, memory, mprotect

```
#define base_address 0x00005555555551e7
```

I know that the literal `base_address`can be read and written but I can only do that using gdb, for example, if base_address is stored in `rax`

```
mov $0x00005555555551e7, %rax
mov (%rax), -0xc(%rbp)
mov -0xc(%rbp), %eax
```

so the value of `eax` is zero, however in gdb:

```
(gdb) set {int}$rax = 1
```

it sets the value of `*0x00005555555551e7` to 1. However doing that in C;

```
int *addr = (int*)0x00005555555551e7;
*addr = 1; //SIGSEGV permission denied of writing
```

So I'm trying `mprotect()`:

```
int ret = mprotect(addr, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE);
```

But the status of ret is -1 if I do so.

In the manual of mprotect(), it says

> addr must be aligned to a page boundary.

so I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309299/how-to-align-memory-address) to align it to page boundary (using the power of 2 page value)

```
int i_addr = (base_address + ((1<<12) - 1)) & ~((1<<12) -1);
int *addr = (int*)i_addr;
int ret = mprotect(addr, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE);
assert(ret==0);
```

but this time too, the status of ret is -1. I'm lost now, I don't know what to do.

Comment: You're using `int i_addr`. On a 64 bit machine this will be truncated to 32 bits. Use `uintptr_t`. Also, the alignment code aligns _upward_ to next multiple of the page size. When you do this, the actual starting address of the area you want to protect will _not_ be covered. You want to round _downward_. So: `uintptr_t i_addr = base_address & ~((1<<12) -1);`

Comment: But, even with this, you can't just access semi-random memory locations because they won't be _mapped_ into memory unless something is already there (e.g. program/data text, stack, sbrk, mmap, .so, etc.). I'm not sure that [apparent] `gdb` access guarantees that. And, you should print/show the _specific_ error you get (e.g. `EINVAL`, `EACCES`, `ENOMEM`, etc.).

Comment: One issue may be that gdb by default disables [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).  So even though that address may be accessible when running under gdb, in a normal run your program may be mapped somewhere completely different, which does not include that region.  You can only mprotect a region that is already mapped.  Probably you should step back and explain *why* you are trying to do this.  What larger goal are you intending to accomplish?

Comment: Further, when you align downward, you _may_ need to increase the _length_ of the area for `mprotect`. The simplest way is to specify a length of `PAGE_SIZE` (e.g. 4096). Or, [with suitable casting]: `base_address - i_addr + sizeof(int)`

Comment: Additionally, doing `set $rax = 1` just sets the value in the RAX register to 1 (_not_ changing memory as you claim). So, we'd need to set that and step through some code that utilizes RAX in some way. I'm not sure you're even setting memory with `gdb` at all.

Comment: `print *(int*)0x00005555555551e7` shows 1 as I set `rax` to 1. Sorry @CraigEstey, it should have been `set {int}$rax = 1` since we are referencing `rax`, sorta `mov $0x1, (%rax)`.

Comment: When I do: `print *(int*)0x00005555555551e7` in `gdb`, I get: `warning: value truncated Cannot access memory at address 0x555551e7`

Comment: I really think you should address the issues that Nate and I have raised (including _why?_). Otherwise, this is an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/785231 Do you understand about the downward alignment? What is special about `0x00005555555551e7` [relative to `/proc/<pid>/maps`]? The TL;DR is that you can _not_ do `mprotect` on an area that is not already mapped.

Comment: @CraigEstey I've tried rounding downward as you said, but did not seem to work (also using uintptr_t instead of int). I really should identify the `errno`, so I can give you more info.

Comment: Again, what we've been saying is that it will _**not**_ work. There is _nothing_ you can do to make this work (without the above actions I mentioned (e.g. `mmap`)). Several issues have been pointed out to you. You really need to address them to understand why this won't work. Perhaps you need to download the kernel source and examine the `mprotect` syscall code

Comment: Yeah, I think it is impossible to do without mapping the memory first. However I request,  just another question @CraigEstey, would it be possible to map the memory manually ("by hand"), for mprotect to not throw `ENOMEM`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246919/discussion-between-user1094822-and-craig-estey).